# Heroku Error: Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Getting this error in node.js but not sure why.

`index.js` lives in my root level `app` folder and looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

and when running `heroku open` I get an error:

```
2017-03-15T15:41:18.615808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-03-15T15:41:18.616112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-03-15T15:41:18.733009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Procfile looks like: `web: node ./app/index.js`

Can post more code but looking at other issues these seem like the solutions people have but in place..

Comment: Which port does your process manage to bind to?

Comment: @HoriaComan it doesnt ? it says failed to bind to $PORT...

Comment: Can you get your application to log something? Perhaps do a console.log(process.env.PORT) to see what value it gets? Perhaps it's somehow undefined and the app starts listening on 8080.

Comment: @HoriaComan ok I have it working of sorts but now have a 404 coz it cant find my index.js. do you know anyway of hot reloading heroku?

Comment: @HoriaComan is my procfile alright?

Comment: I don't think Heroku has hot reloading. You need to push a new slug to it (through GitHub, travis etc.)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

Alright try this stuff out

```
const express = require('express'), app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/', (req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```